# SQLAlchemy- How do I filter datetime on Month?

Tags: python, sqlite, datetime, filter, sqlalchemy

My current code is looking like this

```
start_month_june= dt.date(2012 ,6, 1)
end_month_june = dt.date(2012 ,6, 30)
june_temps = session.query(Measurement.date, Measurement.tobs).filter(Measurement.date >= start_month_june, Measurement.date <= end_month_june)
```

This code currently selects all the dates between June 1 and June 30th for 2012. How can I filter it for the month of June for all the years in my dataset (2010-2018) instead?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work in sqlite but does not work with (at least) postgres.

It extracts the month as a string from the date.  The months are 0 padded, meaning they look like '01..06..12', so for June we use '06'.

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

session.query(Measurement.date, Measurement.tobs).filter(func.strftime('%m', Measurement.date) == '06').all()
```

- [sqlalchemy's func docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func)
- [sqlite's strftime docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)